# Subtraction between two mysql subqueries

Tags: mysql

Iam trying to subtract two sub queries. The two tables are listed below

```
COM_PAYMENTS

+++++++++++++++++++
tender_id | amount
+++++++++++++++++++
   10     | 200
   10     | 345
   22     |  18
   25     |  45

COM_RECEIPTS

+++++++++++++++++++
tender_id | amount
+++++++++++++++++++
   10     | 10
   10     | 15
   22     | 13
```

What iam trying to achieve in a query is First i need to find the sum of amount of tender_ids of both COM_PAYMENTS and COM_RECEIPTS and the total amount of COM_PAYMENTS need to be subtracted from total amount of COM_RECEIPTS.

```
Example: The out put in this case should be:

tender_id | Total

    10      520 (200 + 345 = 545, 10 + 15 = 25, 545 - 25= 520)
    22      5   (18 - 13)
    25      45 ( Since COM_PAYMENTS doesnt have any recrds)
```

This is what i have tried, but where ever data is there in COM_RECEIPTS only its showing the total, for others its not subtracting its showing blank:

```
(select
SUM(com_payments.amount)
FROM com_payments
WHERE view_sales_report.tender_id = com_payments.tender_id) -
(select
SUM(com_receipts.rec_amt)
FROM com_receipts
WHERE view_sales_report.tender_id = com_receipts.tender_id)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT tender_id
     , SUM(amount) total
  FROM
     ( SELECT tender_id, amount FROM com_payments
        UNION ALL
       SELECT tender_id, amount*-1 FROM com_receipts
     ) x
 GROUP 
    BY tender_id;
```

Moving forward, I would suggest you have only one table, which records all transactions - payments and receipts - with a transaction_id and a column recording the type of transaction.

Comment: Wouldn't work: Imagine for a moment there's a row in com_receipts with tender_id = 10; amount=-200

Comment: how could it not? We know nothing about how the tables get filled

Comment: yes we do, and with this we only know how the tables SHOULD get filled...

Comment: @ipiero I think this works fine whatever the circumstances.

Comment: @Strawberry yes, the UNION ALL was what I was aiming for ;)

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this is what you need:

```
SELECT tender_id, SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM (
    SELECT tender_id, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM COM_PAYMENTS
    GROUP BY tender_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT tender_id, SUM(amount * -1) AS amount
    FROM COM_RECEIPTS
    GROUP BY tender_id
  ) a
GROUP BY tender_id
```

Comment: I think there's too much query here.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT pa.amount)-IFNULL(SUM(DISTINCT re.amount) , 0) FROM com_payments pa
LEFT OUTER JOIN com_receipts re ON pa.`tender_id` = re.`tender_id` GROUP BY pa.tender_id
```

Comment: I agree that in the absence of a PRIMARY KEY, this isn't really a table in an RDBMS sense. Still, i think we have to allow for the possibility that someone might tender the same amount twice.